# Mixing percentage and pixels within css method syntax

Tags: jquery, css, methods, syntax, calc

My goal is to center an absolute element. Like `calc(50% - 123px)` but with the help of jQuery. What's the right syntax for it?

```
element.css({
    width: pageWidth,
    left: '50%' - pageWidth / 2
})
```

Comment: Any reason in particular why you want it in jQuery? You could achieve this effect just with CSS. Using: `left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, 0);`, it won't matter when you change the width dynamically as the element will always be centered

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is this

```
element.css({
    width: pageWidth,
    left: '50%',
    margin-left: - pageWidth / 2
})
```

Comment: It would be `margin-left: - pageWidth / 2`